# Access room database from service and activity

Tags: android, android-room

I have a service that runs in background. It starts on device's boot and totally separated from activity.

If I want to use room, how should I use `databaseBuilder` ? Is it ok, to build it twice - for service and an app ? Will it build the same instance of database ?

Comment: did u use jobintentservice??

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a single instance of your database for the entire application. You can use a singleton to archive this, such as this:

```
@Database(entities = [YourEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class YourRoomDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun yourDao(): YourDao

    companion object {

        private var INSTANCE: YourRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): YourRoomDatabase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context, YourRoomDatabase::class.java, "yourdb.db").build()
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }

        fun destroyInstance() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can call it from wherever you like like this:

```
YourRoomDatabase.getInstance(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Room database builder` will create database on its first run. After that, its job is to open existing (created) database. For example we can think of `callback` function on database open. That might be different from Activity to Activity. So, you can use builder as much as you need in the application. But you should maintain good practice of closing `connections, statements and resultsets`, etc... properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i need save my location to Rooom database from service, this service use call of type Coroutine, and inside coroutine one thread, my code:

call type coroutine inside oncreate in my service

```
 GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main) { 
      onNewLocation()  //call to metodo of type suspend 
}
```

you should created method type suspend, becasuse is asyncronus call

```
 suspend fun onNewLocation() {
      
     //call Room database inside thread

       val thread = Thread {
            val db = myDatabase.getDataBase(this@LocationUpdatesService)

            db.locationDao().addLocation(locationentity)
        }

        thread.start()

}
```